# Declaration is incompatible with void

Tags: c++

Hi I am getting an error saying declaration is incompatible with void. I am not really sure how to fix this i would appreciate some help. This is for a program that runs an Avl tree. I also have .h files.

```
template <typename Comparable>
void AvlTree<Comparable>::rightRotate(AvlNode *&y) const
{
    AvlNode *x = y->left;
    AvlNode *x2 = x->right;

    x->right = y;
    y->left = x2;

    y->height = max(height(y->left),
                            height(y->right)) + 1;
    x->height = max(height(x->left),
                            height(x->right)) + 1;

    return x;

}

template <typename Comparable>
void AvlTree<Comparable>::leftRotate(AvlNode *&x) const
{
    AvlNode* y = x->right;
    AvlNode x2 = y->left;

    y->left = x;
    x->right = x2;

    y->height = max(height(x->left),
                            height(x->right)) + 1;
    x->height = max(height(y->left),
                            height(y->right)) + 1;

    return x;

}

template <typename Comparable>
void AvlTree<Comparable>::insert(const Comparable &x, AvlNode *&t) const
{
    if(node == NULL){
        return (newNode(t));
    }

    if(key < x->t){
        x->left = insert(x->left, t)
    }

}
```

Comment: You seem to not be entirely sure about whether your functions should return a value or update a reference argument. You need to make up your mind. (It seems like you skipped ahead a bit optimistically in your C++ book. Review the introduction to functions.)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return something in a void declared method:

```
template <typename Comparable>
void AvlTree<Comparable>::insert(const Comparable &x, AvlNode *&t) const
{
    if(node == NULL){
        // you cant return something in a void method
        return (newNode(t));
    }

    if(key < x->t){
        x->left = insert(x->left, t)
    }

}
```

Comment: hi thank you for your comment. Any suggestion you can give to help me fix my problem?